# Im making Checkers in pygame the way I want a piece to move is with 2 mouse clicks but I don't know how to do that

Tags: python, pygame

Right now I have a drag mechanism which is the code below does someone know how I can make it so the first click selects a piece and the second click moves the piece. By simply intending another mousebuttondown into the first mousebuttondown nothing happens.

```
while not game_over:
    clock.tick(FPS)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            start_x = event.pos[0]
            start_y = event.pos[1]
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
            end_x = event.pos[0]
            end_y = event.pos[1]

            board.valid_moves(start_x, start_y)
            board.get_mouse_pos_and_place(start_x, start_y, end_x, end_y)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a variable that is set when the mouse is clicked the first time. When the mouse is clicked the 2nd time do the movement.
Initialize `start_x` and `start_y` with `None`. Set the variables when the mouse is clicked. Use the variables when the muouse is clicked again:

```py
start_x = None
start_y = None

while not game_over:
    # [...]

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:

            if start_x == None and start_y == None:
                # select piece
                start_x, start_y = event.pos

            else:
                # do movement
                end_x, end_y = event.pos
                
                board.valid_moves(start_x, start_y)
                board.get_mouse_pos_and_place(start_x, start_y, end_x, end_y)

                # prepare for next move
                start_x = None
                start_y = None
```

You can improve the algorithm by checking that the first click is on a piece:

```py
if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:

    if start_x == None and start_y == None:
        # select piece
        click_x, click_y = event.pos
               
        is_on_piece = # [...] check if click_x, click_y is on a piece
        if is_on_piece:
            start_x = click_x
            start_y = click_y 
  
        else:
            # [...]
```